# How to know that rollback has been executed ? [@Transactional]

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have the following case:

I'm iterating over my `Affiliate` entities and for each of them I need to persist and update data in one unique transaction. So I have a service with a method annotated with Spring `@Transactional` annotation (where data is created and updated) but I don't know how can I see that the transaction has been rollback for an affiliate ?

I would like to know that for a special `Affiliate` the transaction has been rollback and retrieve a custom error code from my service..

This was my service before using Spring:

```
public void savePostingPaymentDetails(List<Posting> postingsToUpdate, List<PaymentPostingDetail> detailsToInsert, Payment payment) {
    logger.info("DB ACCESS : INSERT PAYMENT DETAILS & UPDATE POSTINGS");
    long begin = System.nanoTime();

    this.em.getTransaction().begin();

    try {
        // TEST
        // 1 - Save Payments
        this.em.persist(payment);

        // 2 - Save Details
        for (PaymentPostingDetail ppd : detailsToInsert) {
            this.em.persist(ppd);
        }

        // 3 - Update Postings
        for (Posting p : postingsToUpdate) {
            if(p.getSignature() != null)
            {
                p.getSignature().setModification("withholding-tax.pay", new Date());
            }
            else
            {
                logger.error("The Posting with id = " + p.getIdentifier() + " has no PersistenceSignature ?!");
            }
            this.em.merge(p);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Unexpected error on saving/updating the DB.", e);

        this.em.getTransaction().rollback();
        logger.info("RollBack done.");

        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(JobStatus.ABNORMAL_END_OF_EXECUTION_ERROR.getCode());
    }

    this.em.getTransaction().commit();
    logger.info("Details inserted & Postings updated.");

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info("Execution time = " + ((end-begin) / 1000000) + " milliseconds.");
    logger.info("----------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Now I have this:

```
@Transactional
public void savePostingPaymentDetails(List<Posting> postings, List<PaymentPostingDetail> paymentDetails, Payment payment)
{
    logger.info("DB ACCESS : INSERT PAYMENT DETAILS & UPDATE POSTINGS");
    long begin = System.nanoTime();

    this.paymentRepository.save(payment);
    this.ppdRepository.save(paymentDetails);

    for(Posting p : postings){
        if(p.getSignature() != null)
        {
            p.getSignature().setModifiedAt(LocalDate.now());
            p.getSignature().setModifiedBy(PayCopyrightWithholdingTaxProcess.SIGNATURE);
        }
        else{
            p.setSignature(new PersistenceSignature(LocalDate.now(), PayCopyrightWithholdingTaxProcess.SIGNATURE));
        }
        this.postingRepository.save(p);
    }

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info("Execution time = " + ((end-begin) / 1000000) + " milliseconds.");
    logger.info("----------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

But how can I return let us say a special integer (instead of `System.exit()`) if the transaction has been rollback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called User managed  Transaction(UMT) and Container managed Transaction (CMT)
When you are using `@Transactional` you are actually delegating the transaction management to your Spring container (CMT), which is responsible for e.g opening and closing the transaction for you. It
rolls back automatically when `unchecked Exception` is thrown like `NullPointerException`, or `RuntimeException` ). For checked
exceptions you have to specify when the rollback  is supposed to occured `@Transactional(rollbackFor=myCheckedException.class)`.

You can also listen, observe how the transaction is doing with a `TransactionalEventListener` and react with some AOP listening code like shown [here](https://dzone.com/articles/transaction-synchronization-and-spring-application). But You are not ultimately managing the Transaction, Spring is doing for you. The client code *can't react with some custom code*, when something special happens, because the management of the transaction is delegated to Spring.

Therefore you have to fall back on the User managed Transaction, where you open your transaction, commit it and react in case of a rollback. That is exactly the purpose  of UMT: *giving total control of your transaction*.

from your old code you may get something like:

```
public int savePostingPaymentDetails(List<Posting> postingsToUpdate, List<PaymentPostingDetail> detailsToInsert, Payment payment) {

    int returnCode = 1 // 1 -> "success" , 0 -> "failure"

    logger.info("DB ACCESS : INSERT PAYMENT DETAILS & UPDATE POSTINGS");
    long begin = System.nanoTime();
    long end = 0;

    this.em.getTransaction().begin();

    try {
        // TEST
        // 1 - Save Payments
        this.em.persist(payment);

        // 2 - Save Details
        for (PaymentPostingDetail ppd : detailsToInsert) {
            this.em.persist(ppd);
        }

        // 3 - Update Postings
        for (Posting p : postingsToUpdate) {
            if(p.getSignature() != null)
            {
                p.getSignature().setModification("withholding-tax.pay", new Date());
            }
            else
            {
                logger.error("The Posting with id = " + p.getIdentifier() + " has no PersistenceSignature ?!");
            }
            this.em.merge(p);
        }
        this.em.getTransaction().commit();
        end = System.nanoTime();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        returnCode = 0;
        logger.error("Unexpected error on saving/updating the DB.", e);

        this.em.getTransaction().rollback();
        logger.info("RollBack done.");

        // e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(JobStatus.ABNORMAL_END_OF_EXECUTION_ERROR.getCode());
        return returnCode;
    }

    //this.em.getTransaction().commit();
    logger.info("Details inserted & Postings updated.");

    //long end = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info("Execution time = " + ((end-begin) / 1000000) + " milliseconds.");
    logger.info("----------------------------------------------------------");
    return  returnCode = 1;
}
```

*PS*: on a side note, best practice would have you to *throw an Exception* when your commit fails, instead of special code.

your new method signature could be:

```
public void savePostingPaymentDetails(List<Posting> postingsToUpdate, List<PaymentPostingDetail> detailsToInsert, Payment payment) 
throws MyFailedDbOperationException, OtherException {

}
```

and Throw the exception on your catch block

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.error("Unexpected error on saving/updating the DB.", e);

    this.em.getTransaction().rollback();

    logger.info("RollBack done.");
    throw MyFailedDbOperationException("my db operation failed");
}
```

Comment: It would be cleaner and easier using Spring Data repositories and a litle annotation instead of managing this with `@PersistenceContext EntityManager` :) The problem is that I cant let Spring transaction do what he want because I need to exit with a special exit code if something is wrong... Thank you for your explanations I will do it as you suggested.

Comment: If this post was helpful to you, would you consider adding +1 to the answer ? it would be nice from you :)

Comment: on another note , I don't know if Spring Data repositories will help with you `special code` problem,  but keep us informed!!

Comment: Spring Data repositories will not help to have an exit code but they already contain methods for saving & updating data. It is just to say "If I use them I want to use them everywhere, and not here I use Spring repository and there I go for `EntityManager`". But Ok, mad problems - mad solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a listener (`@TransactionalEventListener`) to be informed of a rolled back transaction (the listener can be bound to the different phases of a transaction). See section 16.8 of https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html for more information (requires Spring >= 4.2)

Comment: Thank you didn't know about this. I'm reading how this can help me :)